# Change WebBrowser UserAgent via Cordova - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, javascript, html, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have unique question, and I know it might be asked before in some form, but the answers doesn't help me for my use case.

I am using Cordova/Phonegap on WP8 and looking to change the UserAgent of that Browser to something other than the traditional. I know that you an use `.Navigate(uri, null, "Custom Agent")` - but since my WebView is open and never changing pages or navigating to another page (other than index.html) - I need to make sure all AJAX requests that originate from the CordovaView (WebBrowser) have a custom UserAgent. Is this possible?